# How to write conditional logic and list comprehension in python using np.where and np.select

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

You can write conditional logic and list comprehension in python using np.select and np.where.

The below is the condition basis which we have to write the logic.

```
Condition
X1=Age 
X2=Segment 
If X2="Bike" & if 25<=X1<45 Then T1=7
Else 0
```

You can achieve this writing in two ways in python. Using np.select and np.where.

```
Using np.where
df['New_Column']=np.where((df['Segment]=='Bike')&(df['Age']>=25)& (df['Age]<=45),7,0)

Using np.select
Condition=[(df['Segment']=='BIKE') & &(df['Age']>=25)& (df['Age]<=45)]
Values=[7,0]
df['New_column']=np.select(Condition,Values)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
condition= [ (df['segment']=='BIKE')  & (df['Age']>=25) & (df['Age']<45),7,0)]
choice = 7
# with np select

df['T1']= np.select(condition, choice, default=0)
# with np.where

df['T1'] = np.where((df['segment']=='BIKE')  & 
                    (df['Age']>=25) & 
                    (df['Age']<45), 
                     choice,0)
```

Comment: In case i have a computed column, means a column which is created on basis of some calculation, then how Shall i apply the logic in it. Eg. Column name Computed = df['Num'] *100/df['Char']

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `pandas`:

```
df['T1'] = 0 # Set the default value
df.loc[(df['segment'] == 'BIKE') & (df['Age'].between(25, 44, inclusive=True)), 'T1'] = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we can also achieve it by using `np.select()` by defining the list comprehension in python.
Writing the conditions in one set of list and values in another set of list and then using `np.select()`. The below is the example.

```
conditions=[((df_data['segment']=='Bike') 
             &(df_data['Age']>=25) &(df_data['Age']<45))]

values=[7]

df_data['Var1']=np.select(conditions,values)
```